# Hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY And String Sequences

Tags: hibernate

Because of some issues with implementing Spring Security on top of a legacy database schema, our user id needs to be generated by a sequence, but stored as a VARCHAR(9). So, we'll convert on the database side to make this invisible to the code side (sequences/triggers/etc).

However, as far as I know, this will blow up if mapped via GenerationType.SEQUENCE like this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="MYGENERATOR")
```

Since the field will be populated via trigger, can I just map with a GenerationType.IDENTITY?

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: I can't try it, as our DBA has not made the necessary changes to our development schema. Hence me asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.  You can set the type of identifier field to String and use the GenerationType.IDENTITY strategy.

The one thing to ensure is that the generated id can be fetched using the JDBC api (PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys). This [page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0656.html) has more details on what is needed to make it work.